# Get date from DOM element

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

I am trying to fetch date `01/08/14` from child information with Simple HTML DOM .

My code is:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="display_cr" class="loose-spacing tid">    
    <div class="review_by">By <strong>juand1</strong> on 01/08/14 06:51 AM (PST)</div>
    <div class="review_by">By <strong>juand1</strong> on 01/08/14 06:51 AM (PST)</div>
</div>
```

**PHP:**

```
protected function scrap_date($review) {
    $res  = ''; 
    $date = $review->find('div[class=review_by]');   
    if (isset($date)) { 
        foreach ($date as $div) {
            $data = '';
            foreach ($review->find('div[class=review_by]') as $element) {  
                $data = $element->outertext;
            }
            $res[] = $data;
        }  
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just wrap the date in its own `<span class="date">` and reference it directly?

Comment: Yes , Bit I am getting this DOM from other site by use CURL...So I can  not change HTML DOM Structure .. Any more suggestion please...Many Thanks for helping me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
foreach ($review->find('div[class=review_by]') as $element) {
  $data = $element->innertext;
  preg_match("/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}/", $data ,$match);
  if(sizeof($match) > 0 ){
    res[] = $match[0];
  }
}
```